# Запятая перед "и"

Tags: пунктуация

*Я почти не помню деда.

Помню только: Волга, небо,

Я – мальчишка-непоседа,

Тот, которого всегда

«Мой разбойник» называл он,

Обнимал рукой беспалой,

И вихров моих касалась

Колким снегом борода.*
[**Разбойник**](https://omiliya.org/content/razboynik)

Я считаю, что запятая перед "И вихров моих касалась..." не нужна, но эта запятая оставлена предыдущим редактором, с которым автор согласен. Рассудите нас, пожалуйста.

Comment: А на основании чего вы считаете, что не нужна? Здесь есть тонкость, на основании которой можно и не ставить. Но если автор и редактор против, то они лучше знают.

Comment: На основании правила о союзе "и" при однородных членах предложения. Но я уже поняла свою ошибку.

Comment: Напрасно считаете ошибкой. Здесь как вариант вполне можно считать однородными членами. Тут разговорно-поэтическая речь, последнее предложение вопреки обычной грамматике можно считать однородным членом в ряду "называл", "обнимал". Разумеется, если автор против, то он видит другую грамматику, более естественную. Но если он вдруг захотел бы без запятой написать, то понятно почему, имеет право.

Comment: Вот поэтому и признаю свое понимание ошибочным. Но спасибо за поддержку!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я почти не помню деда.
Помню только: Волга, небо,
Я – мальчишка-непоседа,
Тот, **которого всегда
«Мой разбойник» называл он,
Обнимал рукой беспалой,**
И вихров моих касалась
Колким снегом борода.

**Запятая нужна,**  это конец придаточного определительного предложения с союзным словом КОТОРЫЙ.

**Схема:** Помню только: Волга, небо,
Я – мальчишка-непоседа,
Тот, которого называл он,
Обнимал,
И (при этом) вихров моих касалась...

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla! Открылись глаза!

Comment: *это конец придаточного определительного предложения с союзным словом КОТОРЫЙ.*.  Да? А не обычное ССП? Он называл, обнимал, и борода касалась.

Comment: Здесь сложное предложение с различными видами связи. (1) Помню только: (2) Волга, (3) небо, (4) Я – мальчишка-непоседа, Тот, (5) которого всегда «Мой разбойник» называл он, Обнимал рукой беспалой, (6) И вихров моих касалась Колким снегом борода.
Бессоюзная связь между (1) и остальными предложениями; сочинительная связь: бессоюзная между 2,  3, 4 и союзная между 4 и 6.  Предложение 4  распространено придаточным определительным 5 с союзным словом КОТОРОГО, причем  указательное слово  ТОТ образует обособленный оборот.

Answer (score 0):

И вихров моих касалась колким снегом борода - простое предложение в составе сложного, поэтому перед союзом И запятая нужна.